# ImportError: No module named 'rospkg' on hydro <SOLVED>

Tags: ros, python, python3, rospkg, morse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi poeple,

In installed ros-hydro on ubuntu 13.04.

I am trying to get the "morse-simulation":  http://www.openrobots.org/wiki/morse/
to work with ros hydro. but I always get an error message when starting my simulation (for example the "tutorial-1-ros.py"):

```
[helpers.loading] Module not found: Could not import some ROS modules. Check your ROS configuration is ok. Details:
No module named 'rospkg'
[helpers.loading] Could not load the class RosRequestManager in morse.middleware.ros_request_manager
[helpers.loading] Could not create an instance of morse.middleware.ros_request_manager.RosRequestManager
```

when running "import ros" in python3 i get:

```
>>> import ros
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ros/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    import roslib
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from roslib.launcher import load_manifest
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 42, in <module>
    import rospkg
ImportError: No module named 'rospkg'
```

any idea for a solution of this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/85211/importerror:-no-module-named-%27rospkg%27--on-hydro-%3Csolved%3E/) by [tub](https://answers.ros.org/users/4793/tub/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2013-09-30

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on 2013-10-02**:
What if I do not use catkin? Because all along I am using rosbuild. Sorry if making any inconvenient I am a new programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

well.. after some more tinkering I found out how to solve this.

I found a solution for the problem:
it seems that python3 finds ros, but it does not find specifically the packages rospkg, catkin_pkg and yaml, which are required for morse-simultion to work.

Thus you can just do:
after using virtualenv for a virtual python3 installation you can just do:

```
pip-3.3 install catkin_pkg rospkg yaml
```

(if yaml installation does not work this way, then just do sudo apt-get install python3-yaml)

After that reconfigure morse with the new python directories (in my case /home/user/bin/python3.3) and everything should work fine.

---

Originally posted by [tub](https://answers.ros.org/users/4793/tub/) with karma: 76 on 2013-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-10-03**:
You should edit this, and place the answer here..

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-04-03**:
I second to @trinighost; separating question and answers makes it so easier for other readers to find what was the effective solution/workaround. I've moved the finding to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you follow the [MORSE installation instruction for ROS](http://www.openrobots.org/morse/doc/latest/user/installation/mw/ros.html), you'll see you indeed need to install `rospkg` for Python 3. Everything should be explained there: if something is missing, please feel free to fill a [bug report on MORSE](https://github.com/morse-simulator/morse/issues) or ask for support on morse-users@laas.fr.

---

Originally posted by [severin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2119/severin/) with karma: 240 on 2013-10-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1